# How to extract all URLs from an XML document in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to check all of the URLs in an XML document for Server-side Request Forgeries (SSRF).  But in order to do that, I need a reliable way to get any and all URLs from an XML document - including strings that look like URLs, XML NS URLs, and so on.

While this initially seems simple, I was not able to find any existing libraries or answers on Stack Overflow that do this.  Note that in this case, I want to be able to do this even if there is no DTD or other metadata definition for the XML file in question.

Does anyone know what the best way to extract all of the URLs in an XML document would be in C#?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Also please note this is not an HTML/XHTML question.

Comment: low tech approach, which will likely find many false positives `\w+://[^\s]+` or  `\w+:(\/?\/?)[^\s]+` failing this you will need to parse the xml `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Using regex (regular expressions) is not recommended for text that is not regular like html or xml.  Without seeing the xml it is impossible to give an answer.

Comment: @jdweng the idea is to make something that works heuristically well for any possible XML

Comment: Is the URL an attribute or innertext?  I looked at samples of SSRF and the URL in the innertext are not easy to identify.

Comment: @jdweng It could be either attribute or innertext.  Suggestions for either would be awesome though